# Linq - search string in entity or sub-entity

Tags: c#, linq

I have entities for Suppliers and Items, where Suppliers have a one-to-many relationship with Items.

I need to search a string in both, so that search result will return the following:

1. All Suppliers whose name contains the search string and all of their Items.
2. All Suppliers who have Items whose name contains the search string.

So far I've been doing it with two lists and then doing a Union:

```
var suppliers = repository.Suppliers.Where
       (s => s.Name.Contains(searchString)).Include(Items);

var itemSuppliers = repository.Suppliers.Include(Items).Where
                (s => s.Items.Any(i => i.Name.Contains(searchString));
```

Is there a better way to do it, preferably with one query?

Thank You

Comment: The second statement has two wheres. I wonder it compiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
repository.Suppliers.Include(Items).Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString) || s.Items.Any(item => item.name.Contains(searchString)));
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank You! 
A follow-up, if I may: does the Include first loads all items and then filters them, or sends the query to the DB?

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg: as long as you did not iterate it or serialize it, it will remain as a query (totally safe)

Comment: A little problem with the query:
when it finds at least one Item that contains the searchString, it returns all of the Items for the Supplier. How to make it return only the corresponding Items?

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg: I think your previous queries also have the same problem. There's no way to exclude items in the Include query (it's just eager loading the entities). You need to filter out the results in the select query.